# All layers disappear after using OpenLayers

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin

Not trying to do anything complicated here... I have a .csv with date/time and lat/long data. When I load it into QGis as a delimited text layer, everything appears fine at first:

[image]

But, when I try and use ANY of the openlayers plugins, it eats all my data. Now NONE of the datapoints I had before are visible, and removing OpenLayers from the legend doesn't seem to do anything. If I try and add in the layer again, it still remains invisible.

[image]

Anyone have any idea of what's happening here, or an alternative to the OpenLayers plugin?

Comment: What do you mean by use the openlayers plugins?  What operations are you doing with them when you load them in?  Does the data disappear when you load in the plugin, or after you attempt to perform a command in one of the plugins?  The more detail you can provide about the process you took from loading in the data to when it disappeared, will likely help someone answer your question.

Comment: Literally all I do is go to the Web menu, select a layer from the Openlayers menu to add, and then poof - everything's gone and nothing will display any more. 

After systematically testing every option in OpenLayers, the Bing Maps, Open Street Maps,  and the Apple maps will at least render and be visible as a layer, but the delimited text layer just disappears and refuses to render.

Comment: Nope, nevermind, now none of the layers from OpenLayers will render at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try the "QuickMapServices" plugin instead. It's got numerous benefits over the aging OpenLayers plugin, like not forcing use of a particular CRS.

Comment: Just downloaded it, will be playing around with it shortly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the other great existing answers, you mentioned:

*"After systematically testing every option in OpenLayers, the Bing Maps, Open Street Maps, and the Apple maps will at least render and be visible as a layer, **but the delimited text layer just disappears and refuses to render**"*

When you load an OpenLayers Plugin layer, it sometimes overlays all current layers. To fix this, right-click on the toolbar and check the **Layer Order Panel**. Then enable the *Control rendering order*, this works as a priority order so layers at the top of the list will overlay any layers below the list:

[image: Layer Order Panel]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The OpenLayers plugin can be very flaky at times.

But right away I notice your source data is not in epsg:3857 -- this generally screws up the openlayers plugin as all webmaps are in epsg:3857 and it is not very good at handling the on-the-fly reprojection.

Reproject your data to epsg:3857.  Then try adding that to a map and adding the plugin.  The data is not 'not rendering' -- it's just being reprojected WAY off the screen.

When you add the plugin, it switches the on-the-fly projection to 3857, which is why when you remove the plugin your data is still invisible -- because the on-the-fly projection is still the same.  Note how the on-the-fly projection is different when you start a new map and only import your data.

Comment: ...yep, this is a large chunk of my problem. Thank you Thomas!